# How to efficiently split 1 data frame column to create a new data frame assigning same value to each part of category column

Tags: r

I have rather un-tidy data by category where sometimes there are multiple categories in a single field. I'd like to assign the same value to each category in a category entry after splitting the multi-category entry. For example, if the data is

```
cat <- c("A,B,C", "B", "B,C", "A,E")
val <- c(300, 350, 400, 450)
mydf <- data.frame(cat, val, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

        cat   val
        A,B,C 300
            B 350
          B,C 400
          A,E 450
```

From the first row, I need 300 to be assigned to each category A, B & C, then from the second row 350 assigned to B, 400 assigned to each B and C from the third row and then 450 assigned to A and E in the fourth row.

I came up with a very kludge-y for loop to accomplish this, but I know this is not memory-efficient because it is using rbind on an existing data frame.

```
resultsdf <- data.frame(temp_cats = character(0), 
             temp_vals = numeric(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(mydf)){
  temp_cats <- stringr::str_split(mydf$cat[i], ",")[[1]]
  temp_vals <- rep(val[i], length(temp_cats))
  temp_df <- data.frame(temp_cats, temp_vals, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   resultsdf <- rbind(resultsdf, temp_df)
}
```

Just curious if anyone has a more elegant R-syntax way of accomplishing this to end up with

```
  temp_cats temp_vals
1         A       300
2         B       300
3         C       300
4         B       350
5         B       400
6         C       400
7         A       450
8         E       450
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) stack/unstack** Use `strsplit` to split the strings and then unstack and stack it to get the long form `s` required.  Finally fix up the names and make `temp_vals` numeric since `unstack` coerced them to character.  No packages are used.

```
s <-  stack(unstack(transform(mydf, cat = strsplit(cat, ","))))
with(s, data.frame(temp_cats = values, temp_vals = as.numeric(as.character(ind))))
```

**2) dplyr/tidyr**  Another approach is to use `unnest` in the tidyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
     mutate(cat = strsplit(cat, ",")) %>%
     unnest() %>%
     transmute(temp_cat = cat, temp_vals = val)
```

**2a)** With tidyr 5.0 or later this could be made even shorter (as pointed out by @aosmith in the comments).  `separate_rows` uses `unnest` internally.

```
mydf %>%
     separate_rows(cat) %>%
     transmute(temp_cat = cat, temp_vals = val)
```

Comment: You could also use `separate_rows` instead of the `mutate`/`unnest` combo.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about unnest in tidyr, I'm still mostly using reshape2. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
setnames(cSplit(mydf, "cat", ",", "long"), c("temp_cats", "temp_vals"))[]
#   temp_cats temp_vals
#1:         A       300
#2:         B       300
#3:         C       300
#4:         B       350
#5:         B       400
#6:         C       400
#7:         A       450
#8:         E       450
```